# Where to get Yum-Folders?

Tags: linux, centos6, yum, rhel

I hope this is not off-topic, 
but I need to get these folders:
etc/yum and

etc/yum.repos.d

[image]

from a CentOS6.

Can anyone help me out here?

---

**EDIT:**

@ilent2:
I'm Sorry, I didn't express myself right.
I meant, I allready have yum installed on a RHEL6 system, but want the yum configuration from CentOS6. Is there any way, where I can download these files and folders??

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question.  Is yum installed on your system?  Have your tried `ls /etc/yum.repos.d` and `ls /etc/yum` or `locate yum`.  Could you type the last one of thouse in a terminal an include your output in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used RHEL, but from what I understand CentOS offers a complete replacement of packages/binaries.  Just installing the CentOS repositories onto your RHEL system and installing CentOS and RHEL packages would, as I understand, cause conflicts and possibly an unusable system (as long as you don't install the same binary from both repos, you should be right, perhaps disable the centos repo by default and only enable when you want to install a particular package).

That said, the following link might be useful, the author seems to want to achieve a similar task to you:

http://cotdp.com/2012/07/installing-centos-packages-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux/

The information in the first comment of the above link might be most useful to you.